# How to access multiple value from controls

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of textboxcontrol on my page all with class 'red'. On click of button, how can i retrieve all these values from textboxcontrol at same time in a variable? I also want to avoid empty controls.

i am trying this

```
var values=$('input[class="red"]') ??(what to put here)
function()
{
  return $(this).val()
}
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Traversing/map](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/map) function:

```
var values = $('input.red').map(function () {
  var value = $(this).val() || null; // if value is '', null will be returned
    return $(this).val();
});
```

The `values` variable will be an array containing the all values of your inputs, excluding the empty ones.

If you want to get all the values in one string, you can [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) all the array elements by:

```
var stringValues = values.join(); // values separated by comma
```

Also, for matching elements with a determined class, you don't need to use the [`attributeEquals`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeEquals) selector, you can simply use the [`.class`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/class) selector as is on my example.

Answer (score 1):

```
var values;
$('input[class="red"]').each(function(){
     values = ( $(this).val() ) ? values + $(this).val() : values;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [trim](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.trim) function to check for empty values and values containing more than 1 space.

```
$(document).ready ( function () {
    var strValues = "";
    $("[input[class='test']").each ( function ()
    {               
        if ( jQuery.trim ( $(this).val() ) != "" )
           strValues += $(this).val();
   });
   alert ( strValues );
});


<input class="test" type="text" value="a" />
<input class="test" type="text" value="   " />
<input class="test" type="text" value="b" />
<input class="test" type="text" value="c" />
<input class="test" type="text" value="d" />
<input class="test" type="text" value="e" />
<input class="test" type="text" value="f" />
```